# How to call an API on expansion of a collapsible div and fill its content with the API response using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) 1.6 and I am quite new to it. I have this piece of `html` below

```html
<span ng-repeat="topdata in userData">
  <span style="white-space: pre;">
    <a class="collapsed" data-target="#testThis" data-toggle='collapse' ng-click="getInfo(topdata.user_id)">
      <pre><i class='fa fa-plus'></i><span>Some text</span> </pre>
    </a>
  </span>
  <div id="testThis" class='collapse'>
    <!-- API content goes here -->
  </div>
</span>
```

In the `js` part

```
$scope.getInfo = function(user_id) {
    toSend = {"user_id": user_id}
    $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: /some-url,
          data: toSend,
     }).then(function(response) {
        // fill the response data inside #testThis div
     })
}
```

Currently when the user clicks on the `collapsible span`, it expands and a function is called that calls an `API`. But I don't know how to fill the response of the `API` inside the content of the expanded `span`.

Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the response to the `userData` and bind the collapsed element to it.

For example

```html
<div id="testThis" class='collapse' ng-bind="userData.more"></div>
```

and

```js
}).then(function(response) {
  const userData = $scope.userData.find(data => data.user_id === user_id);
  userData.more = response;
});
```

Here is a live example (I did some necessary changes to make it work but the idea is the same).

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.userData = [{
    user_id: 8
  }];
  
  $scope.getInfo = function(user_id) {
    toSend = {
      "user_id": user_id
    }
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
      //data: toSend,
    }).then(function(response) {
      const userData = $scope.userData.find(data => data.user_id === user_id);
      userData.more = response;
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <span ng-repeat="topdata in userData">
  <span style="white-space: pre">
    <a
      class="collapsed"
      data-target="#testThis"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      ng-click="getInfo(topdata.user_id)"
    >
      <pre><i class='fa fa-plus'></i><span>Some text</span></pre>
  </a>
  </span>

  <div id="testThis" class="collapse" ng-bind="topdata.more | json">
    <!-- API content goes here -->
  </div>
  </span>
</div>
```